# Regex that matches json response

Tags: regex, soapui

I have the following Response :

```
{"uptime": "6589 seconds"}
```

Created an Assertion that Matches with the  regular Expression and validates the response for e.g
uptime.*seconds

This does not work and throws 
Missing token [uptime.*seconds] in Response.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this

Comment: Can you post the exact code?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an script assertion like that :

```
import net.sf.json.groovy.*

jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText('{"uptime": "6589 seconds"}')
def uptime =  "${jsonSlurper.uptime}"
log.info uptime
assert uptime ==~ /.*seconds/
```

For more explanations about groovy regex, you can read [this link](http://mrhaki.blogspot.fr/2009/09/groovy-goodness-matchers-for-regular.html)